# JSON, список данных разных уровней

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode

Получить список имен конкретного уровня JSON данных

```
{
  "ID": "0",
  "Name": "Все",
  "Departments": [
  {
  "ID": "18",
  "Name": "IT офис",
  "Employees": [
    {
      "ID": "4647",
      "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
      "Title": "Менеджер по проектам",
      "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
      "Phone": "+79991112222"
    },
    {
      "ID": "7935",
      "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
      "Title": "Менеджер по проектам",
      "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
      "Phone": "+79991112222"
    },
    {
      "ID": "4648",
      "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
      "Title": "Руководитель проектов",
      "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
      "Phone": "+79991112222"
    }
  ]
},
```

В данный момент знаю два варианта для разделения:

```
id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
firstLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Name"];
secondLabel.text = [[object objectForKey:@"Departments"]objectForKey:@"Name"]
 secondLabel.text = [[[object objectForKey:@"Departments"]objectAtIndex:1]objectForKey:@"Name"];
```

В таком случаи очень неудобно каждый раз добавлять objectForKey, особенно, если такие переходы в глубь хочется автоматизировать. Еще непонятно как грамотно в таком случаи узнать количество элементов

Второй вариант

```
// Создание под таблицы
    NSDictionary *responseDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
  _namesDepart = [NSMutableArray new];
    if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:responseDic])
    {
        NSArray *array = [responseDic objectForKey:@"Departments"];
        [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            [_namesDepart addObject:obj];
        }];

    }
// Вывод
firstLabel.text = [_namesDepart[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
```

Во втором случаи можно достаточно просто узнать количество данных на уровне, но не знаю, как получить список глубже

```
 return [_namesDepart count];
```

Comment: можно как то вопрос уточнить? что надо получиться то - ваш вариант в энумераций массива вполне себе отличный. если надо глубже делайте рекурсию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используй литералы:

[_namesDepart count] замени на _namesDepart.count

[responseDic objectForKey:@"Departments"] на responseDic[@"Departments"]

Также стоит использовать переменные, вместо постоянного objectForKey:

NSDictionary *responseDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData

NSArray *departments = responseDic[@"Departments"];

for( NSDictionaty *department in departments ) {

```
NSArray *employees = department[@"Employees"];
for( NSDictionary *employeer in employees ) {
    NSLog(@"name %@", employeer[@"name"];
}
```

}